# Перемещение в нулевой гравитации

Tags: c#, unity3d, move

Подскажите пожалуйста как реализовать перемещение в нулевой гравитации?
В переменную goDirection должно записываться направление движения игрока, которое зависит от horAxis, vertAxis и cameraHolder.transform.rotation

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Movement : MonoBehaviour
{
public Transform cameraHolder;
public float mouseSensitivity = 2f;
public float upLimit = -70;
public float downLimit = 70;

private float horAxis;
private float vertAxis;

private Rigidbody playerRB;
void Start()
{
    playerRB = GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
}

private void Awake()
{
    Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
    Cursor.visible = false;
}

void FixedUpdate()
{
    Move();
    Rotate();
}
private void Move()
{
    horAxis = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    vertAxis = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    Vector3 goDirection = new Vector3(); // здесь надо указать направления движения

    playerRB.AddForce(goDirection, ForceMode.Acceleration);
}

private void Rotate()
{
    float horizontalRotation = Input.GetAxis("Mouse X");
    float verticalRotation = Input.GetAxis("Mouse Y");

    transform.Rotate(0, horizontalRotation * mouseSensitivity, 0);
    cameraHolder.Rotate(-verticalRotation * mouseSensitivity, 0, 0);

    Vector3 currentRotation = cameraHolder.localEulerAngles;
    if (currentRotation.x > 180) currentRotation.x -= 360;
    currentRotation.x = Mathf.Clamp(currentRotation.x, upLimit, downLimit);
    currentRotation.z = 0;
    cameraHolder.localRotation = Quaternion.Euler(currentRotation);
}
}
```

Comment: Поставь себя на место человека, который ничего не знает о твоём проекте. Твой вопрос звучит как "как сделать что-то, я уже сделал кое-что".

Comment: сам проект: https://yadi.sk/d/B7BpSTniWbKE4Q?w=1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Это один из вариантов:

```
[SerializeField] private Transform _сamera;
private void Move()
{
    horAxis = Input.GetAxisRaw("Horizontal");
    vertAxis = Input.GetAxisRaw("Vertical");

    Vector3 goDirection = new Vector3();
    
    goDirection = vertAxis * _сamera.forward + horAxis * _сamera.transform.right;

    playerRB.AddForce(goDirection, ForceMode.Acceleration);
}
```

так-же можно поставить макс. скорость:

```
    Vector3 velocity = playerRB.velocity;
    if (velocity.magnitude > maxSpeed)
    {
        playerRB.velocity = playerRB.velocity.normalized * maxSpeed;
    }
    playerRB.AddForce(goDirection, ForceMode.Acceleration);
```